# MVC 3 GET Webservice and Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I'm attempting to build a GET webservice that would from website 1 initiate a GET request...sending that request to website 2 and website two would respond by sending a list of objects. I using Json.net to serialize and deserialize the List of objects.

I've put together a POST webservice with the assistance of this question.. [WebService ASP.NET MVC 3 Send and Receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568453/webservice-asp-net-mvc-3-send-and-recieve)

But I've been unsuccessful so far at adapting that example for my new requirement.

Here is what I have so far from website 1..

```
    public static List<ScientificFocusArea> ScientificFocusAreas()
    {
        string apiURL = "http://localhost:50328/Api/GetAPI";

        //Make the post
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

        //var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(body);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiURL);
        Stream stream = null;
        try
        {
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.Method = "GET";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            }
        }

        List<ScientificFocusArea> listSFA = WebService.GetResponse_ScientificFocusArea(request);

        return listSFA;
    }

    public static List<ScientificFocusArea> GetResponse_ScientificFocusArea(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        List<ScientificFocusArea> listSFA = new List<ScientificFocusArea>();

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    throw new HttpException((int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
                }

                var end = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    end = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();

                    listSFA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ScientificFocusArea>>(end);
                }

                response.Close();
            }
        }

        return listSFA;
    }
```

Then on the website 2...

```
public class GetAPIController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Api/GetAPI/

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetScientificFocusAreas()
    {
        //Get list of SFAs
        List<ScientificFocusArea> ListSFA = CreateList.ScientificFocusArea();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListSFA, Formatting.Indented);

        //Send the the seralized object.
        return Json(json);

    }

}
```

Also, on website 2, I've registered this route for the incoming request...

```
        context.MapRoute(
"GetScientificFocusAreas",
"Api/GetAPI/",
new
{
    controller = "GetAPI",
    action = "GetScientificFocusAreas",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
}
```

);

I'm currently getting the error.. he remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Any help would me greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems like a routing issue. I would start with the RouteDebugger which can be found [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx). This tool gives insight into which routes your URL is hitting.

The code I use for a HTTP GET is a bit different that what you have above. It's included below.

```
    public T Get<T>(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    throw new HttpException((int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
                }

                var end = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    end = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }

                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();

                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Binder = new DefaultSerializationBinder();
                JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(end));
                T deserialize = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);

                return deserialize;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApiException(string.Format("An error occured while trying to contact the API. URL: {0}", url), ex);
        }
    }
```

The other issue I see is in the `GetScientificFocusAreas()` method. On the second line of the code the objects are converted to JSON. Which is fine, but the last line of code the json is passed into the `Json()` method. Which converts the string into Json yet again. When using the JSON.Net library use the `Content()` method in the `return` instead of `Json()` and set the content type to **application/json**

The reasoning for using an external Json converter rather than the internal converter is simply the internal json converter has a few known issues. JSON.Net has been around for years and is solid.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your suggestion and there is an error on this line...serializer.Binder = new DefaultSerializationBinder(); Am I missing a namespace or class?using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: Ignore my last comment Chuck, I was able to get it to work. serializer.Binder = new DefaultSerializationBinder();